# start 0 opacity and onClick set opacity to 100

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I start `welcome.png` set to `opacity 0` and when button (id= "c1") is clicked to slowly fade in to opacity 100?

```
<img id = "welcome" src="img/welcome.png"></img>

<a class="Btn" id= "c1" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('var').value='a_';mkr(this)">Button1</a>
```

I tried adding the below. But did not work.

```
<a class="Btn" id= "c1" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('var').value='a_';mkr(this); javascript:document.getElementById('welcome').className = 'opac';">Button1</a1

.opac {
    opacity:1;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No JQuery needed(some people might say not enough JQuery :D ). This should be enough for whta you need.

```
<img id = "welcome" src="img/welcome.png" />

<a class="Btn" id= "c1" onclick="document.getElementById('welcome').className = 'opac';">Button1</a>
```

CSS:

```
#welcome { opacity:0; transition: opacity 1s; }
.opac{opacity: 1 !important;}
```

**Demo**: (works in chrome, not tested in other browsers)
http://jsfiddle.net/zKkun/

Comment: also as a sidenote `</img>` is an **invalid HTML tag** and should be removed!

Comment: Why downvoted twice? [Not enough JQuery?](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-Hk1mt-RKYLc/UOkxShm6NrI/AAAAAAAACqo/LVmqHOfWV7g/s1600/20091116-so-large.gif)

Comment: Hahahahahhh nice image! :) like! :) Nobody said jQuery was needed, it's just this question attracted **a lot** of people with really poor knowledge and probably bad attitude. I gave on this Q 3 downz on A. You were not the one. On the contrary! ;) I would give a +2 if you only removed that inline JS...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan the inline JS is a bad programming practice but not related to his issue neither invalid code, I only provided him with a simple CSS3 way of doing what he wanted

Comment: yup exactly, nice one

Answer (score 0):

```
        $('#c1').click(function(){
            $("#welcome").animate({
                    opacity:1                   
            },5000);
        });
```

Comment: oGeez: yes you are right. It's not a good idea to fade an opaque element. Animate would be better.              $('#c1').click(function(){
   $("#welcome").animate({
            opacity:1     
                 },2000);
    });

Comment: How is in: `.css({opacity : 1}).fadeIn('slow')` **fadeIn()** supposed to happen after you set `opacity: 1` ?

Comment: Yes! roko, i got the point. fadeIn() is of no use as opacity is set to 1. animate would be better. $('#c1').click(function(){ $("#welcome").animate({ opacity:1  },2000); });

Comment: ... what you did now is **exactly** the same as `$('#welcome').fadeTo(5000,1);` so no, animate in not needed ;)